# What would happen when eden space and survivor space are full?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

As mentioned on the following page:
http://oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

What would happen when the tenured generation has space available and both the eden space and survivor space are full with objects with valid references and none of the objects in survivor space has reached its threshold to be moved to tenured generation?

Comment: probably the same thing that links provides - *Content Server Request Failed
Error Unable to retrieve content. Security access denied.
Back to previous page*

Comment: Voted to reopen. There's no possible way that this question can be construed as a recommendation request.

Answer (score 2):

Reaching the tenuring threshold is just one condition for moving to the old generation. The other one is that there's no more room in the young generation. The objects will go directly from Eden to Old Gen, skipping the survivors if they are full.